# SmartStore FMDatabase is not open

Tags: mobile

I'm developing an iOS hybrid app using Salesforce Mobile SDK. I'm using SmartStore to save sObject information. Although I'm facing some problems. 
The first time I open the app and log in I receive the following message while 
registering soup: "The FMDatabase  is not open." But if I hide the app and reopen it I can use SmartStore normally. Obviously I want to avoid this. So, any suggestions...?

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Just update the SDK from 1.3 to 1.4

Comment: Glad to hear, as a thumb rule, you should always use the latest available version of the Mobile SDK. I've learnt this the hard way myself - spending long hours scratching my head on issues which got resolved by themselves once I upgraded.